# Calendar widget (JavaScript) and usability issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, usability

I want to use Calendar widget to help users select date.

I wish use any standalone calendar or as a jQuery plugin. In my project I'm using jQuery, and I don't want to use any other frameworks.

I saw a lot of calendars, but they all has the same problem. I will describe it now, see below:

There are possible two way to show up calendar:

1. to click on some button, icon etc to show it up.
2. to click on text field (where we will see result of date selection) to show it up

I chose the second way. In my case I will have only ONE text field without any addition icons, buttons etc.
When this text field get focus the calendar will be show up. When user selected any date, calendar will be hidden, and text field will show selected date.

And here I have main problem...

After appearing the calendar the text field is loosing focus. And after selection date, focus did not got back to this field, and <kbd>tab</kbd> key (on keyboard) beginning run from start.

From usability point it would be good if when user finish selection date from calendar, and selected date shows up in text field, he can keep using <kbd>tab</kbd> key to go to next text field.

Any ideas how to solve it ?

P.S. I have only one idea, but I don't like it, because it looks me little bit ugly

When calendar is shows up, I could destroy event handler (focus event) on text field.
When user selected date and calendar is disappearing, I can set focus on this text field and attach event listener (focus) for this text field again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery-UI's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) doesn't send focus to the popup calendar widget, instead the user is expected to use alternative control to change the date, additionally this would allow the user to manually type the date in should they so choose.

Comment: user should not write date manually, they can make error in anytime.
That is why i'm thinking what they should select it from calendar.
And they have to have ability to use keyboard or mouse to fill form.
Jumping from field to field usually happens by mouse clicks or by pressing on TAB key. And i don't like jquery UI. Thanks

Comment: @user1016265, the ui widget is designed with accessibility in mind. The user will have to use a keyboard, mouse, or equivalent input device anyway. If they've disabled JavaScript, they'll need to manually input the date too.

Comment: I just meant what after using jquery UI calendar you can't keep using TAB key to jump to next field, you can try by your self

Comment: @user1016265, tabbing works fine with the datepicker; if you focus a field where the datepicker shows, and then hit tab, your focus will go to the next interactive element. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: @user1016265, Here's [a fiddle i threw together](http://jsfiddle.net/JkyeL/) where tabbing works just fine.

Comment: You see, it's almost work  as i expect but one problem still here, and I know how tolve it already, thanks by "Tom van der Woerdt".

Look into your example, and follow me:
1. Click on first field
2. By clicking TAB move to DATE field
3. Select date 
4. And then click TAB again
and you will see what first field became selected again :(

at least it works if do not select any date, yes in this case it works as expected.

P.S. Thank you, I will use jQuery UI Datepicker. It's more flexible as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Since JavaScript is a singlethreaded language, you can simply set a variable (`disableEvents` or something) to true and set it back to false when you've called `.focus()` - this won't cause any troubles and doesn't require much work.